# Angular Meteor tutorial ng-include empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, meteor

I'm working through my first Angular Meteor tutorial, the [socially](http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/bootstrapping) tutorial. I made it to the end of the Bootstrapping page, ran it, and got a blank page.

This is my file structure.

```
 ~/socially$ tree 
    .
    ├── client
    │   ├── main.html
    │   └── main.js
    ├── index.html
    ├── node_modules
    │   └── angular
    │       ├── angular-csp.css
    │       ├── angular.js
    │       ├── angular.min.js
    │       ├── angular.min.js.gzip
    │       ├── angular.min.js.map
    │       ├── bower.json
    │       ├── index.js
    │       ├── package.json
    │       └── README.md
    ├── package.json
    └── server
```

My main.js contains this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';

angular.module('socially', [
  angularMeteor
]);
```

My main.html contains:

```
<p>Nothing here</p>
```

And my index.html contains:

```
  <body ng-app="socially">
  <div ng-include src="'client/main.html'"></div>
  </body>
```

I was expecting this to produce a page with `<p>Nothing here</p>` inside the body, but it just has the `div` from index.html. This is the html produced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>



</head>
<body>
<div ng-include src="'client/main.html'"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">__meteor_runtime_config__ = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent("%7B%22meteorRelease%22%3A%22METEOR%401.3.1%22%2C%22meteorEnv%22%3A%7B%22NODE_ENV%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22TEST_METADATA%22%3A%22%7B%7D%22%7D%2C%22PUBLIC_SETTINGS%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22ROOT_URL%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F%22%2C%22ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX%22%3A%22%22%2C%22appId%22%3A%2214v9c1u524x5u1l3ybao%22%2C%22autoupdateVersion%22%3A%22948c522486d699c7a0a4ad2168f2060a08d86389%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionRefreshable%22%3A%227e7eeab70fbd6563db07bb8d57ab943bfb729f89%22%2C%22autoupdateVersionCordova%22%3A%22none%22%7D"));</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?hash=8de51f9d86e95ae2ffee15a8db324a1decccba3e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js?hash=199010c1afa99e8bd5ece688951432123b502723"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor-base.js?hash=78d760bd25caaa0aaaa51b630ff14fdbfddf0a80"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mobile-experience.js?hash=228175c74a6bdd2cc7d213d791ad7633cde48eb6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/base64.js?hash=b81b0d2b7b33328b3b89ee0f5a255a9ccdc7becb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ejson.js?hash=06477dace2029b30779531d0eee8ee0c400e4525"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules-runtime.js?hash=939c79dfda40f1a849312e224b12b3aa11452782"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/modules.js?hash=ccee19a941146eabb5cf036e67e9b0ac60771d01"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/jquery.js?hash=649d9f4d10ffd1b725db74dbd268ff935227a999"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/check.js?hash=b15bbb57fb6b392447aae5d6adc7dd1183d0f2a3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-compiler.js?hash=e1688ae6cf3e302b7737b0ce56fa790cc0a9be03"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript.js?hash=66523b499a44a9bde66a5c90da84c2f620fa9038"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/id-map.js?hash=c7ee77be99a8b1f8ec984e2c122864f9604525d5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ordered-dict.js?hash=0389f6fd93358207ec24f56a66b65cea226646a1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/tracker.js?hash=b267c37effdf4af331d16fc647c0370c2eaff44d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/es5-shim.js?hash=6c690fb6264db23904871b6b2accd6fee75a2e67"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/promise.js?hash=76f9fa05244092de9aa9eb2b32e81d4c7cb48166"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ecmascript-runtime.js?hash=4e4ed2f265b0ab04be3c225afadff0a6ad1ad00b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/babel-runtime.js?hash=25e64a1d62222dd3d1646486c94e81a3639043f5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/random.js?hash=94fe15f9966e8181e2b6e610bf7a2c58c40a4ce7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo-id.js?hash=8810275f539ed7bbad9202ce7639600ff8ee26cf"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/diff-sequence.js?hash=727c5f356b359104f0b5586eab1b7866bce68589"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/geojson-utils.js?hash=15d58e409f3e68223a6c7bf4b3a5dbb41c0eb9e2"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/minimongo.js?hash=a0d533dedc4ce27ae70b6a13ae3b8227d2d21159"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/retry.js?hash=134b8c4e4edb2b4a96ea22178dfdc4702226293a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-common.js?hash=96850536f446242cf0c8811bc434af3346d26bf1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reload.js?hash=1917116c9d89d442051faef6edf03691d5fd10fe"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-client.js?hash=4b5dd6c64affcb1f152409ce9ede08973e06a2b7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp.js?hash=752b775e282ca59c21ca09b9cc61f5fffb9ea2a1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ddp-server.js?hash=f22a106538ade54bd1190c4d309f2f94bdd3ec9b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/allow-deny.js?hash=28b7b02fffd8490f81f75fa9580e532e61473c0a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/insecure.js?hash=5679de9a1eaf70c1c18f8c3bf9493ebe2e4caa33"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo.js?hash=bc4cc4faf274ce28cefc812067aa65c0d4025ed4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-var.js?hash=6d3dc00fae3831478105b808e0b227f7047be039"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-css.js?hash=28195a94bf7be7891ced328ed580307f7ac6ed54"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-minifier-js.js?hash=555d6f310158f363207df43e0353de4a4883d7af"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autopublish.js?hash=bc72b03fb56c2a80ef076107d3c27287cbc7ca08"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/angular-templates.js?hash=ce3b4bfcad27ea08de340b11a81805e15cccb98b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/pbastowski_angular-babel.js?hash=dbe97ad32000a68151e5fdd930cbe3b007257f63"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/webapp.js?hash=7431a11f1c671b350504fe7192b94219e5200359"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/livedata.js?hash=e7fb2e783bc81b00b914c2e27966b7b6d3d081b6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/hot-code-push.js?hash=9121bd39124b5010787be320ca559344b6691712"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/launch-screen.js?hash=56bda4b972e8035450feba7f866a060872c46fbc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autoupdate.js?hash=028c641918eb50a83f0f93187f6373bc617e73f7"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/global-imports.js?hash=ac678c19d4121c3b4c51b689b329565c83937915"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/app/app.js?hash=8ac76200586de52441313a248355bb91e7a9bddb"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the [zip of that step](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular-socially/archive/step_00.zip) and running it? You may have forgotten to add the packages (`pbastowski:angular-babel` and `angular-templates`) or run `npm install --save angular angular-meteor` to add the appropriate packages. Check your `.meteor/packages` file, and your `node_modules`/`package.json` to make sure everythings there

Comment: Thank you! Looks like I did run `npm install` but there was a permissions error. The zip helped. Is that from the Angular Meteor website?